# Controls in designer are not shown on form

Tags: vb.net, controls, designer

I have a panel contains many controls, the designer file has its code and I can not find them on the form and I can not see them on document outline window although when trying to add a new panel with same name I get an error saying 'The name wowPanel is already in use by another component.'
What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Getting an exception at design time can do strange things to a form.  Certainly making controls disappear. That however tends to make a loud bang.  Looking at the form's Designer.vb file is the first thing to do.  Restoring from source control is usually second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced my designer file with an old version then everything goes very well.

Answer (score 0):

Look for all instances in your form code where you have the name/text wowPanel

REM out these lines temporarily

REM out any subroutines if you have event subroutines for the wowpanel

Next add the new wowPanel and Name it as so "wowPanel"

Now UN-REM (un-remark) all the code statements you REMmed out earlier.

That ought to do it.

Comment: Ok, I will try it out, but the most important what is that strange this behavior?

Comment: If the controls are listed in the designer file and each controls entry is intact and not corrupted then I can only guess its nested or invisible, but you should be able to check those points out in the designer file by viewing it in notepad.

Comment: I had to say that this component is not exist in 'Document Layout' window, however the code compiler does not complain about any missing or invalid code. then I will assume that behavior is something like a corruption, please let me know what are the signs of designer file corruptions.

Comment: Sorry Zaf, It did not work completely, the designer rewrites everything the designer file then all commented code in designer file was overwritten by VS., So I'll try something else.